# How to write a custom function to sort and pivot dataframe in python

Tags: pandas, numpy, pivot-table, user-defined-functions

In the dataframe below

[image]

I want to write a `def` function that takes in a data frame and does the following :

1. select `Location` , `Group`, `Income_Yr1` : `Income_Yr3` columns
2. sort the dataframe using the `Group` column from `lowest` to the `highest` value
3. create a pivot table for `mean`,`median` and `standard deviation` ( making it 3 tables per `Income_Yr` or possibly combine them as one ) for `Income_Yr1`, `Income_Yr2` and `Income_Yr3`

```
# DataFrame using arrays.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
# initialise data of lists.
data = {'Gender':['F', 'F', 'M', 'F','M', 'F', 'M', 'M','F', 'F', 'M', 'F','M', 'F', 'M', 'M','M','F', 'F', 'M'],
        'UID':[1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1011,1012,1013,1014,1015,1016,1017,1018,1019,1020],
        'Location':['PHX','PHX','PHX','PHX','ATL','ATL','ATL','ATL','HOU','HOU','HOU','MIA','MIA','MIA','MIA','MIA','DEN','DEN','DEN','DEN'],
         'Group':[3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5],
        'Income_Yr1':[32112,34214,45575,22106,32612,34216,47515,22906,32112,34511,45525,12106,52112,54214,45015,22986,32112,34214,47518,22175],
         'Income_Yr2':[52112,54215,65515,72109,52616,64217,77515,52906,52145,38512,65516,32157,63152,57218,51017,42997,38125,36253,49589,32598],
        'Income_Yr3':[52143,54239,65557,72116,52660,64273,77551,52969,52500,38201,65169,32795,63288,57180,51173,42970,38205,36301,59591,32580]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

See below for my attempt, I am open to other approaches

```
# read in the dataset 


def pivot_table (data): 
    
     #1. import dataset and select the desired columns, I want to include all column names with string 'Income'

    df1 = df[['Group','Location','Income_Yr1':'Income_Yr3']]
     #2 sort the data using 'Group' column
    df1 = df1.sort_values('Group')
     #3a create pivot table for mean
    pd.pivot_table(df1,index = ['Group','Location'],values ='Income_Yr1',columns = 'Location',margins = True)
     #3b create pivot table for median
    pd.pivot_table(df1,index = ['Group','Location'],values ='Income_Yr1',columns = 'Location',aggfunc = 'median', margins = True)
     #3c create pivot table for std
    pd.pivot_table(df1,index = ['Group','Location'],values ='Income_Yr1',columns = 'Location',aggfunc = np.std, margins = True)
    #3d Income_Yr2: create pivot table for mean 
    pd.pivot_table(df1,index = ['Group','Location'],values ='Income_Yr2',columns = 'Location',margins = True)
     #3e Income_Yr2: create pivot table for median
    pd.pivot_table(df1,index = ['Group','Location'],values ='Income_Yr2',columns = 'Location',aggfunc = 'median', margins = True)
     #3f Income_Yr2 create pivot table for std
    pd.pivot_table(df1,index = ['Group','Location'],values ='Income_Yr2',columns = 'Location',aggfunc = np.std, margins = True)
      #3g Income_Yr3: create pivot table for mean 
    pd.pivot_table(df1,index = ['Group','Location'],values ='Income_Yr3',columns = 'Location',margins = True)
     #3h Income_Yr3: create pivot table for median
    pd.pivot_table(df1,index = ['Group','Location'],values ='Income_Yr3',columns = 'Location',aggfunc = 'median', margins = True)
     #3i Income_Yr3 create pivot table for std
    pd.pivot_table(df1,index = ['Group','Location'],values ='Income_Yr3',columns = 'Location',aggfunc = np.std, margins = True)
##########
#test code 

pivot_table(df)
```

Thanks

Comment: can you add your expected outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `melt` then `groupby`

We can use a dictionary comprehension then to sort and split your dataframes.

```
df1 = pd.melt(df,
             id_vars=['Group','Location'],
             value_vars=df.filter(like='Income').columns.tolist()
            ).sort_values('value') # default is lowest to highest.

df2 = df1.groupby(['Group','Location','variable'])['value'].agg(['mean','median','std'])
```

---

```
#now for your split dataframes.
out = {income_yr : frame for income_yr, frame in df2.groupby(level=-1)}
```

---

```
print(out['Income_Yr2'])

                                   mean   median           std
Group Location variable
1     HOU      Income_Yr2  52057.666667  52145.0  13502.211831
      MIA      Income_Yr2  32157.000000  32157.0           NaN
2     MIA      Income_Yr2  53596.000000  54117.5   8629.910428
3     PHX      Income_Yr2  60987.750000  59865.0   9466.207878
4     ATL      Income_Yr2  61813.500000  58561.5  11779.239888
5     DEN      Income_Yr2  39141.250000  37189.0   7333.583770
```

#### Function

Not sure of the benefit of a function here unless you have very complicated data pipelines or need to re-use this piece of code in many places but this should work,

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Dict

def transform_and_split_data(data: pd.DataFrame) -> Dict[str,pd.DataFrame]:

    df1 = pd.melt(data,
            id_vars=['Group','Location'],
            value_vars=data.filter(like='Income').columns.tolist()
        ).sort_values('value') # default is lowest to highest.

    
    df2 = df1.groupby(['Group','Location','variable'])['value'].agg(['mean','median','std'])

    return {income_yr : frame for income_yr, frame in df2.groupby(level=-1)}
```

Comment: This is very good, one last thing-How can I get the `grand total` of `mean`, `median` and `std`  for `print(out['Income_Yr2'])` row-wise and column-wise. Ideally in pandas pivot `margins = True` does the trick

Comment: @nasa313 `.sum(axis=1)` ?

Comment: where do I include `.sum(axis = 1)` . Please can you edit and include in your code? Thanks

Comment: @nasa313 lots of ways to do this, you're just adding on a column. But i'm confused, why do you need a sum of a median, standard deviation and a mean. What does it achieve?

Comment: I want to get the `grand total`

Comment: do you mean the grand total across _all_ incomes? what would be better if you provided a sample output, please read [mcve] and [ask] @nasa313